# Why is this question still "on hold"?

Tags: support, specific-question, on-hold-questions

After [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815345/test-if-estimator-is-unbiased) was put on hold, I proposed an edit (which was accepted), clarifying what was presumably the OP's intended meaning. Given that the edit was more than 24 hrs ago, is it normal for the question to still be "on hold"? Is something more required to remove the "on hold" status?

Comment: The question has three votes to reopen now, two more are needed. It was over the weekend, when the site is slower.

Comment: This is not a request to reopen, but is asking for support to understand why it hasn't been reopened. (Thank you for your suggested explanation above.)

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/218359) you can see how (and when) people voted in the reopen queue.

Comment: ...now 4 votes to close...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it has not (yet) acquired the required number of votes (5) to reopen it.

Comment: (Reopened now.)

Comment: Thanks ... I really should have noticed [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) before asking.